# Codename One for Android 2.3.5?

Tags: java, android, codenameone

I compile simple GUI project in Eclipse with CodeName One plugin.
It works in their simulator and online build works but at my HTC WildFire S with Android 2.3.5 I have the message "There is a problem parsing the package".

So I have put the Android "hints" in CodeName One :
android.targetSDKVersion and android.min_sdk_version  set to 10.

### As a result the online build fails with this info:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed :
>   uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared
>   in library [com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1] 
>   /home/ec2-user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.aar/c2029d859fd8146aea03623953116eed/AndroidManifest.xml
>   as the library might be using APIs not available in 10    Suggestion:
>   use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 10,         or increase
>   this project's minSdk version to at least 14,         or use
>   tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force usage (may lead to
>   runtime failures)

---

So I have add to the Android "hints" in CodeName One this values

```
tools.overrideLibrary android.support.v4
android.overrideLibrary android.support.v4
android.tools.overrideLibrary android.support.v4
android.tools:overrideLibrary android.support.v4
android.tools:overrideLibrary "android.support.v4"
```

but this does not help.

I have no idea where is Android manifest in CodeName One and don't know how to set tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force usage.

Their online support recommended to ask question here.
But they say that Android 2.3 can be supported.

Comment: why would you want to support android 2.3

Comment: Support for both eclipse as well as Android 2.3 has been closed long time ago. Why are you still using both of them ?

Comment: I use that phone because there are no new phones of this size on the market. I can use it by one hand even when I drive the bicycle off-road. Also it fits into the pocket of my shirt. And this project is for the cheap phones for some reasons.

Comment: I don't know what codenameone is, but the recent versions of the support lib do not support api below 14 as you can see in the error message. Also, using eclipse for android development has not been supported for like 4 years. Please just use android studio

Comment: Codename One supports Eclipse and they make multi-platform binaries for Windows, iOS and Android from the same code and have their own simulator. Also they say that they support Android 2.3. And they do not support Android Studio.

Comment: And actually Android Studio seemingly does not support the Android 2.3 so I installed the Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and Android Development Tools plugin and it works for HTC WildFire S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in supporting older releases of Android is in explicitly disabling Google play. We include google play services for location API's by default so you can disable that by simply adding the build hint:

```
android.playService.location=false
```

This will indicate to us that you are uninterested in the default setting and play would be disabled entirely. Once it's off you probably won't have support libs or anything related to that but it's hard to guarantee as these things change. Google itself dropped support for these old devices years ago and it's challenging for us to support them.

To complete the process you will also need to add the following hints:

- `android.buildToolsVersion=23` - uses older Android build tools for the build process since newer versions dropped compatibility
- `android.targetSDKVersion=14` - target an older version of Android as the main target. This disables some features such as permission prompts etc
- `android.min_sdk_version=10` - Indicates the lowest supported SDK, 10 is 2.3.x

Comment: I added that location hint and my SDK 10 hints but have the same text about android.support.v4 in error log.

Comment: Try setting `android.buildToolsVersion=23` & `android.targetSDKVersion=14`

Comment: With android.buildToolsVersion=23 & android.targetSDKVersion=14 it builds but then the phone cannot parse the package.

Comment: Is this with `android.min_sdk_version=10`?

Comment: android.buildToolsVersion=23 android.targetSDKVersion=14 android.min_sdk_version=10  - now it works at Android 2.3.5 HTC WildFire S, thanks :-)

Comment: Great! FYI you should accept the correct answer by checking the V next to it, this will reward you with a few points which will help you in the future to do things such as attaching screenshots to your questions etc.

Comment: Shai, should we edit the answer to list all 3 hints? I did not use the android.playService.location, it worked for me with android.buildToolsVersion=23 android.targetSDKVersion=14 android.min_sdk_version=10

Comment: Correct. I edited the answer to reflect the discussion